# Using Django TextChoices field in template if statements without hardcoding

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Given a model like

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   class FooTypes(models.TextChoices):
      OK = "F", "Ok"
      BAR = "B", "FooBared!"
   foo_type = models.CharField(max_length = 1, 
                               choices = FooTypes.choices)
```

How can I use an IF statement in a template using FooTypes.OK or FooTypes.BAR (and not hard coding 'F' or 'OK' etc.).

e.g. Something like

```
{% if item.foo_type == FooTypes.OK %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if its the way to go but you could just pass FooTypes via context

```
 'foo_types': FooTypes
```

and now

```
{% if t.foo_type == foo_types.OK %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a verbose declaration, why not explicitly declare the choices in the field definition like:

```
  type_field = models.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_TYPE_LENGTH,
        choices=(
            ("foo", "FOO"),
            ("bar", "BAR"),
            ("baz", "BAZ"),
        ),
        default="foo",
    )
```

Then you can use Django template filters on the first item of each tuple which is the name stored in the db. For example:

```
{% if obj.type == "foo" %}
...
{% elif obj.type == "bar" %}
...
{% elif obj.type == "baz" %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Changing the display value of the choice in templates is as straightforward as changing the second value of the choice tuple, e.g. going from "foo" to "fooBaz" requires changing the line:

```
("foo", "foo") -> ("foo", "fooBaz")
```

Comment: Its no less verbose, and you're still repeating the choice values in the template. What if "foo" changes to "newFoo" - have to remember to change in both the model and any templates.

Comment: Well in either case you still need to have a direct DB reference for the actual choice field? The second value of the tuple is what will be rendered by Django.

Going from "foo" to "fooBaz" is as good as saying in your model declaration:
("1", "foo") -> ("1", "fooBaz"),

You don't need to change your templates nor make DB migrations.